# QWC2 - Projects not available as themes

Tags: qgis, qgis-server, qwc2

We have a folder accessible by QGIS server containing some projects to be served as WMS:

[image]

Projects are available in the qwc admin qui when creating a new theme:

[image]

There is a theme for each project:

[image]

I wonder why not all the themes are available in QWC2 theme section:

[image]

I tried deleting browser cache as well as ctrl-F5 (Firefox), but the themes are still missing.

Any advice one some kind of "refreshing" the QWC2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you did not generate the new service configuration by clicking on the button  in the home tab in QWC Admin ?

It generates all the services configuration files and will take into account all the changes you have made in the tabs. If you don't click on the button in the Home tab, there are no changes in the config and application will not see the new projects.

[qwc-config-generator](https://github.com/qwc-services/qwc-config-generator)

[qwc-admin-gui](https://github.com/qwc-services/qwc-admin-gui)

If you have already clicked on the button to generate configuration, look at QGIS Server log if it can get project settings of all your projects.